# Python program for Word Search II

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, tree

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/) -

> *Given a 2D board and a list of words from the dictionary, find all
>   words in the board.*
>
> *Each word must be constructed from letters of a sequentially adjacent
>   cell, where "adjacent" cells are those horizontally or vertically
>   neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once in a
>   word.*
>
> ***Note:***
>
> - *All inputs are consist of lowercase letters `a-z`.*
> - *The values of
>     `words` are distinct.*

Here is my solution to this challenge -

> ```
> class Solution:
>     def __init__(self, board, words):
>         self.board = board
>         self.words = words
>
>     def find_words(self, board, words):
>
>         root = {}
>         for word in words:
>             node = root
>             for c in word:
>                 node = node.setdefault(c, {})
>             node[None] = True
>         board = {i + 1j * j: c
>                  for i, row in enumerate(board)
>                  for j, c in enumerate(row)}
>
>         found = []
>         def search(node, z, word):
>             if node.pop(None, None):
>                 found.append(word)
>             c = board.get(z)
>             if c in node:
>                 board[z] = None
>                 for k in range(4):
>                     search(node[c], z + 1j ** k, word + c)
>                 board[z] = c
>         for z in board:
>             search(root, z, '')
>
>         return found
> ```

Program explanation - I first build a tree of words with root `root` and also represent the board a different way, namely as a one-dimensional dictionary where the keys are complex numbers representing the row/column indexes. That makes further work with it easier. Looping over all board positions is just `for z in board`, the four neighbors of a board position `z` are just `z + 1j ** k` (for `k` in `0` to `3`), and I don't need to check borders because `board.get` just returns `None` if I request an invalid position.

After this preparation, I just take the tree and recursively dive with it into each board position. Similar to how you'd search a single word, but with the tree instead.

Here is an example input/output -

> ```
> output = Solution([
>   ['o','a','a','n'],
>   ['e','t','a','e'],
>   ['i','h','k','r'],
>   ['i','f','l','v']
> ], ["oath","pea","eat","rain"])
>
> print(output.find_words([
>   ['o','a','a','n'],
>   ['e','t','a','e'],
>   ['i','h','k','r'],
>   ['i','f','l','v']
> ], ["oath","pea","eat","rain"]))
>
> >>> ['oath', 'eat']
> ```

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Awkward API**

It seems strange to initialise a `Solution` object with various info that we provide again in the call of the method `find_words`.

Actually, looking for places where `self` is used makes it pretty obvious: the instance is never used.

It is a good occasion to watch the [Stop Writing Classes talk from Jack Diederich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

*To be continued ?*